# How to dispatch events from an OpenLayers overlay to the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When adding an overlay element to a map in OpenLayers, I can set the *stopEvent* property of the overlay to true. This enables me to handle different events like mouse moves, clicks etc. on the overlay element.

But I also would like some events not be stopped, especially the *wheel* event. I would like to have this event propagated, so that the zoom behaviour of the map works even when the mouse is over the overlay.

How can I achieve this? I can intercept the *wheel* event in the overlay, how can I send this to the map element or wherever it is needed to trigger the noemal scroll behaviour?

Comment: How about using the map functions according to the event that was captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records:

As I am using this for a JavaFX integration [(mapjfx)](https://www.sothawo.com/projects/mapjfx/) I capture the wheel event, send it to the Java side of the integration and in/decrease the zoom level there and send it back to Javascript. So I don't need to worry about handling it in the Javascript layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer-events to none for overlay target html element.

CSS

```
#marker {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS

```
new Overlayer({
    element: document.getElementById('marker')
})
```